# Find $\operatorname{Pr}\left ( Y< 0.5\mid X< 0.5 \right )$ with the given joint probability density function

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y.$ Find $\operatorname{Pr}\left ( Y< 0.5\mid X< 0.5 \right )$ with the joint density function
$$f\left ( x, y \right )= \left\{\begin{matrix} 6xy & {\rm if}\,0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 2- 2x\\ 0 & {\rm otherwise} \end{matrix}\right.$$
I think I need to find the marginal density functions of $X$ and of $Y$ but I don't know how.
If successful, then we use double integrals to find $\operatorname{Pr}\left ( Y< 0.5, X< 0.5 \right )$ and $\operatorname{Pr}\left ( X< 0.5 \right ).$
I will continue the @tommik's idea as following. We obtain
$$\operatorname{Pr}\left ( Y< 0.5, X< 0.5 \right )= \frac{\int_{0}^{0.5}\int_{0}^{0.5}6xy{\rm d}x{\rm d}y}{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2}6xy{\rm d}x{\rm d}y}= \frac{\left ( 1/8 \right )^{2}}{1/2\cdot 2}= \frac{1}{64}$$
$$\operatorname{Pr}\left ( X< 0.5 \right )= \frac{\int_{0}^{0.5}12x\left ( 1- x \right )^{2}{\rm }dx}{\int_{0}^{1}12x\left ( 1- x \right )^{2}{\rm d}x}= \frac{11/192}{1/12}= \frac{11}{16}$$
$$\Rightarrow\operatorname{Pr}\left ( Y< 0.5\mid X< 0.5 \right )= \frac{1/64}{11/16}= \frac{1}{44}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the definition

$$P(Y<0.5|X<0.5)=\frac{P(X<0.5,Y<0.5)}{P(X<0.5)}$$

The marginal density of X is the following

$$f_X(x)=12x(1-x)^2$$

thus...

Comment: @haidangel: $f_Y(y)$ is not needed. You need $f_X(x)=\int f(x,y)dy$. Did you try first doing a drawing to realize the correct integral bounds? Show your attempts and I will help you to solve the problem

Comment: @haidangel : The denominators you showed are not needed in the calculation. moreover the first denominator is wrong because the support is  a triangle. 

The correct answer is the following

$$P(X<0.5,Y<0.5)=6\int_0^{0.5}x dx \int_0^{0.5} y dy=\frac{6}{64}$$

$$P(X<0.5)=\int_0^{0.5} 12x(1-x)^2dx=\frac{11}{16}$$

Comment: @haidangel : thus the result is $\frac{3}{22}$